# The most effective way of merging Microsoft Word documents

Tags: microsoft-word, merge

I have 30 Word documents, each of them contains a little tutorial. I want to merge those tutorials into multiple tutorial collection documents, which don't always contain the same tutorials. For example one document would contain tutorials 1, 2 and 4, another contains 4, 5, and 8.

I want to merge the documents in a way that when I change a tutorial, I can easily update all the tutorial collections that were created from it.

I tried the outline view, but the result was messy when there was too much data.

What would be the most effective way to merge them? (I don't want / I don't have the time to write a new app that does that.)

Comment: You know, it is actually a breeze in HTML format. If you could somehow export your tutorials to HTML, you could create collection files with <iframe> tags that directly transclude your tutorials into a master collection file.

Answer (score 1):

This is like *Fleet Command*'s solutions, but doesn't insert static text or show only 1 page of each inserted document.

1. In the collection document, on the **Insert** tab, in the **Text** group, don't click the **Object** button itself; instead, click the drop-down arrow to the right of the **Object** button, and then click **Text from File**.
2. Select the file to insert.
3. Don't click the **Insert** button itself; instead click the drop-down arrow, and then click **Insert as Link**.

The files are inserted as Word fields. If you make changes in the individual files, you can update the collection document by updating field codes (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all, and then <kbd>F9</kbd> to update).

Answer (score 0):

To do it:

1. Open you collection document.
2. From the **Insert** ribbon, choose **Object**
3. Switch to **Create from file** tab.
4. Click on **Browse** and choose one of your tutorials.
5. Check the **Link to file** box. **Do not forget this important step.**
6. Click OK
7. Repeat as needed.
8. Save your collection document.

From now on, every time you open the document, you will be prompted to update the linked files. Respond with "Yes".

Comment: Seemed like a good idea. The problem is, my documents are bigger than one page and with your method it inserts everything on one page, which doesn't look acceptable.

Answer (score -1):

Steps to Follow:

Step 1: Open '**Microsoft Word**'.
Step 2: In the *Menu bar* click on "**Insert**".
Step 3: Now click on "**Object** [*drop down arrow*]" (Somewhere in the right corner in the Insert menu).
Step 4: And click on "**Select From File**".
Step 5: Then *Browse & Select* your documents and click on "**Insert**".
Step 6: Now go to **File** menu.
Step 7: Click on "**SaveAs**" and Name your new file then click on "**Save**".

*Note: If you are merging different versions of word files then formatting may change.*

***I think this might help you!***

You can also try  [[How to Merge Documents in Microsoft Word]](http://www.wikihow.com/Merge-Documents-in-Microsoft-Word)

Comment: Doesn't work. This method is no different from copying and pasting. In any case, once he updated one of the tutorial, the collection file won't update itself.

Comment: Excactly, it's no difference to copy pasting. I want to be able to update all my collections as fast as possible. But thank you for trying to help me :)

Comment: In my case this works, follow Step 1 to Step 5 after that you must have to use Save As feature (not Save). Anyway, if above doesn't worked for you then you can check this [ http://www.wikihow.com/Merge-Documents-in-Microsoft-Word ] or you can do some youtube search

Comment: Also doesn't work. In fact, the second answer is blatantly wrong. It is about diff sync, not document merger.